# Problem on the stability of discrete-time Markov chains

Tags: markov-process, hidden-markov-model

There is a system which follows the equation:
X(n+1) = X(n) - 1 + A(n), where A(n) is a random variable taking values 0,1,2 with probabilities po,p1 and p2, respectively. Now, X(n) = n and X(n)>=1 are two provided conditions.
I need to find the relation between po,p1 and p2 which ensures stability of the Markov Chain.
Answer is po>p2, but I can't figure out the way to proceed.

My progress:
I tried to derive the steady state matrix, but am not getting po>p2 as the answer. In fact, I don't understand how an inequality like this can be obtained.

Comment: What do you mean by "$X(n) = n$ and $X(n) >= 1$?

Comment: Well, X(n) is the process, and X(n)>=1 is a supplied condition with the problem. This is actual a model of packet arrivals in a queueing network. Basically, n is an index of discrete time, and X(n) = n implies that the number of packets that arrived at time n equals n itself.

Comment: This is a standard trinomial random walk.  I'm not sure what you mean by "stability of the Markov Chain," though.  When $p_0\gt p_2,$ it will have a net drift downward, eventually dropping below any finite value almost surely.  When $p_0 \lt p_2$ it has a net drift upward. The drift will be zero if and only if $p_0=p_2.$ Whatever "stability" might mean, this symmetrical behavior suggests it will not be characterized merely by the inequality $p_0 \gt p_2.$ I suspect you may have omitted crucial information about this process.